# APNS provider that parses data to send

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I would like to create a service that parses data from a feed and then sends notifications to subscribed units.

And I'm note sure how to approach this problem. Would be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be sending less than 1,000,000 push messages per month (greater than that amount you would have to pay), I'd look into [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/) .  They have something called a feed feature that does this:

> Urban Airship has a feature where we
>   will monitor an RSS or Atom feed and
>   send a push notification when a new
>   entry is published. We allow you to
>   set up a template to extract items
>   from the feed to dynamically generate
>   push notifications with content from
>   the new entry. You can easily set this
>   up from the interface at
>   https://go.urbanairship.com/ , but
>   this API allows you to
>   programmatically create them.

So, that might work for you.  Or, you can look into setting up your own server that runs a script, parsing your feeds.  Then you can use [Easy APNs](http://www.easyapns.com/) to send the messages yourself.  I'm using it and it works perfectly for my needs.  For me the learning cure was steep because I'd never done anything besides Obj-C, but it ended up being quite easy to learn.

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer! I might have to do it on a windows server though. Does anyone have any advice how this could be implemented in e.g C#?